# Поиск элемента списка контейнера list и вывод его порядкового номера

Tags: c++, поиск

Как в контейнере `list` найти определенный элемент.
Знаю, что есть `find`. Список заполняется случайными числами. Еще вопрос, как вывести порядковый номер определенного элемента?

Часть кода, только с вводом элементов вручную (для проверки):

```
const int N = 10;
    list<int> box;
    int e;
    cout<<"Введите 10 элементов списка:  "<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        cout<<"[EL-"<<i<<"] = ";
        while(!(cin>>e)) 
    {
        cout<<"~~~~~~~~~~~~~"<<endl;
        cout<<"\aОШИБКА"<<endl;
        cout<<"Введите число:  ";
        cin.clear(); 
        cin.sync();  
    }
    box.push_back(e);
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl;

copy(box.begin(), box.end(), ostream_iterator <int> (cout, " "));
    cout<<endl<<endl;

    int num17=17;
    std::list<int>::iterator findIter = std::find(box.begin(), box.end(), num17);

    auto num = std::find(box.begin(), box.end(), num17);

    do{
    if (!(*num))
    {
    std::list<int>::iterator findIter = std::find(box.begin(), box.end(), num17);
    cout<<"Элемент 17 найден в списке"<<endl;
    cout<<"Его порядковый номер - ";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\aЭлемент 17 не найден в списке"<<endl;
        break;
    }
        }while((*num));
```

Comment: Зачем в списке искать порядковый номер ? Возьмите вектор тогда. А по теме порядковый номер = std::distance(mylist.begin(), findIter);

Comment: Вывести -- просто разменять найденный итератор  if(findIter != mylist.end())
        std::cout  <<  *findIter;

Comment: Задание такое.Нужно через list

Comment: И еще вопрос,проверка у меня некорректно работает,помогите с ней пожалуйста.

Comment: Какая проверка ? Вот написал уже   if(findIter != mylist.end())

Comment: Сейчас попробую.Отпишусь.

Comment: Спасибо,дружище,помог.